# Parallel solution of recurrence equation

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, recursion

One of the most well known parallel algorithms for the solution of recurrence equations is the one proposed by Kogge and Stone (it can be found [here](http://bwrc.eecs.berkeley.edu/classes/ee225c/2000%20225c/Papers/KoggeStone.pdf)). They proved that all recurrence equations of the form:

$x_{1}=b_{1}$
$x_{i}=f_{i}(x_{i-1})=f(b_{i},g(a_{i},x_{i-1}))$

can be solved if the following restrictions are satisfied:
1) $f$ is associative, $f(x,f(y,z))=f(f(x,y),z)$
2) $g$ distributes over $f$, $g(x,f(y,z))=f(g(x,y),g(x,z))$
3) $g$ is semiassociative, that is, there exists some function $h$ such that $g(x,g(y,z))=g(h(x,y),z)$.

**Question**: Are there any other general algorithms that can solve some class of recurrence equations in parallel?

Comment: link is not available? but if it's an if and only if theory there is no other way and I think it should be if and only if.

Comment: link fixed. Tomek, can you explain what is 'efficiently parallel' here ?

Comment: @Tomek: yes. Parallel Algorithms for Knapsack Type Problems by Aleksandrov is one book that deals with this.

Comment: @Suresh: I think that the word 'efficiently' in this context means that it is the fastest possible algorithm. Since this problem involves summing n numbers in parallel it can't be done faster than $O(logn)$ using $O(n)$ processors and that is the complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks for the book, it seems to be good, but unfortunatelly only half of it is available in google books and it'll take me some time till I find hardcopy.

Comment: @Aaron, make the comment an answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For linear recurrences, you may find interesting this recent work:

Adrian Nistor, Wei-Ngan Chin, Tiow-Seng Tan, and Nicolae Tapus. 2009. Optimizing the parallel computation of linear recurrences using compact matrix representations. J. Parallel Distrib. Comput. 69, 4 (April 2009), 373-381. DOI=10.1016/j.jpdc.2009.01.004 http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpdc.2009.01.004

A discussion of the parallel complexity of solving recurrences is available in

Oscar H. Ibarra and Nicholas Q. Tr\&#226;n. 1994. On the Parallel Complexity of Solving Recurrence Equations. In Proceedings of the 5th International Symposium on Algorithms and Computation (ISAAC '94), Ding-Zhu Du and Xiang-Sun Zhang (Eds.). Springer-Verlag, London, UK, 469-477.

Hope this helps.